# How can I get rid the duplication of my reconstructed slice?

Tags: matlab

I'm new in Matlab and I'm working on a project which aims to reconstruct the object from multiple projections taking by parallel beam CT scan, but at the reconstruction stage (by iradon) my reconstructed slice of object is duplicated (one inside another) as in figure [Reconstructed slice 1210](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsUFY.png), and I don't know what is the reason for this duplication? and how can adjust this error?

**EDIT:**

my code:

```
a1=imread ('Asinoimg_row_1210.tif');
AngularIncrement= 360/size(b,2); 
I= iradon (a1,AngularIncrement); 
figure, imshow (I)
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: a1=imread ('Asinoimg_row_1210.tif');

AngularIncrement= 360/size(b,2);

I= iradon (a1,AngularIncrement);

figure, imshow (I)

Comment: Please edit the code into your question, makes it easier to read. Also, what is variable `b`?

Comment: is the value for AngularIncrement correct? The default for D_theta in the `iradon` function is `180/size(a1,2)`;

Comment: Sorry there is a mistake, at line two AngularIncrement = 360/size (a1,2);   and I use 360 because my object rotates 360 degree step 1.2 degree at the time,So, I have 300 projections for my object.

Comment: Please I want any advice to solve this problem, or any source to search in it.